# f string inside dictionary query .pop

Tags: python-3.x

```
dictionary_name =  {'name': 'John', 'Age': '20'}

name = dictionary_name.pop('name')
print(name)
```

This works.

But I would like something like this:

```
dictionary_name =  {'name': 'John', 'Age': '20'}

NAMES    = romnum.pop(name)

name = dictionary_name.pop(f{NAMES})

or name = f{dictionary_name.pop(NAMES)}

print(name)
```

So I would like to query something into a variable and then use it in another query. Any elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out. This is the solution:

```
dictionary_name =  {'name': 'John', 'Age': '20'}
NAMES    = romnum.pop(name)
name    = dictionary_name.pop(f"{NAMES}")
print(name)
```

Comment: Just do `dictionary_name.pop(NAMES)`.  Assuming `NAMES` is a string (since `romnum` isn't defined in your example),  `f"{NAMES}" == NAMES`.